# Timestamp value from database in grid column in Magento

Tags: magento, grid, timestamp

I've created a grid in Magento admin, and I try to get a column from database which is timestamp.

In my grid I added it like this:

```
$this->addColumn(
    'created_at', array(
    'header' => $translateHelper->__('Created at'),
    'align' => 'left',
    'width' => '50px',
    'type' => 'datetime',
    'index' => 'created_at',
    )
);
```

But in my columns my data looks like this:

```
MMMMMMMMM 28, 13 04:June:ssss PM
```

It's really strange because I created other timestamp columns like above, and they show OK. Does anybody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are 3 types for timestamp

```
date
datetime
time
```

Try

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
     'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Created at'),
     'type'      => 'date',  // <-- change to date
     //'format'    => 'Y.m.d',
     'index'     => 'created_at',
));
```